# Is there any range or between kind of function in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a table with three columns in Excel, a,b and c.
One cell has a numeric value `X` [say 25], I need to get the value in the c column such that `X` should be in between min and max column. For `X=25` the value in c is "20" since `X` is between the min and max values for the 5th table row.

I'm looking for a `range` or `between` kind of function, but couldn't find a function with either name.

```
a      b        c 
----------------------------- 
min    max      improvements
0        1      70
2        5      60
6       10      50
11      20      30
21      30      20
31      40      10
41      80      5
```

Comment: Hi mandy, I hope I understood your question correctly; I reformatted it a bit to make it easier for later readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look up in that table of yours which improvement value is correct if some value is "25"; in this case that would mean to match line 5 of your table and return the value 20.

You are looking for `VLOOKUP`, e.g.

```
=VLOOKUP(B12;A2:C8;2)
```

giving

[image]

(**edit**: fixed stupid typo in formula and image, now giving correct result)

Comment: Small correction in the formula:=VLOOKUP(B12,A2:C8,3). That exactly i'm looking for...thanks a lot for your instant help with attachment.